# Swift/Realm only adding last object in provided array (SwiftyJSON)

Tags: swift, realm

I have the following function that I've been working with on to try and keep my code DRY. Everything works perfectly except for only the last object in JSON is being added to Realm. The json param is being coming from alamofire and being converted by SwiftyJSON.

If you add print(object) it's showing 4 objects. Does anyone have any idea why Realm would only save the last iteration of my for loop, but none of the others? Thanks for the help, I'm losing my mind on this one.

Thank you!

```
    /**
    Takes the json provided by *fetchData* to build and save a Realm object by mapping properties to DB attributes. This was built to follow a DRY approach rather than re-inventing the wheel everytime we have to populate our Realm database.

    - Parameters:
        - json: JSON pulled from the mobile API by using a call like *fetchData*.
        - withObject: A realm object (e.g. Module, Audience, Location) that is used throughout the function to build a saveable object.
        - propertyMap: A closure that maps the property value from the json object (in current itteration) to the property of the Realm object.
            - **property**: A tuple from SwiftyJSON
            - **object**: Used to map property from tuple into realm property.

    - Returns: Void

             Example
             ApplicationManager.parseJSON(JSON(locations), withObject: Location(), propertyMap: [
                 "title" : { property, object in newObject.setValue(property.1.string!,  forKey: "title")},
                 "id"    : { property, object in newObject.setValue(property.1.int!, forKey: "id")}
             ])
    */
    static func parseJSON(json: JSON, withObject: Object, propertyMap: [String: (property: (String, JSON), object: Object) -> ()]) {
    // Itterate over every object in the json and provide each object.
    let realm = self.buildRealm()        
    for object in json {
        realm.beginWrite()

        // Itterate over every object and provide each property.
        for property in object.1 {
            // Make sure the property in the JSON is actually in our property map.
            if let propertyMap = propertyMap[property.0] {
                // Execute the property map closure that will set the property.
                propertyMap(property: property, object: withObject)
            }
        }

        // Create the object.
        realm.add(withObject)

        // Commit to realm
        try! realm.commitWrite()
        realm.refresh()
    }
}
```

Comment: You are passing `withObject` into the function, and it's inside the `for` loop to be added to Realm every iteration. This doesn't look right.

Comment: I should have clarified more. The idea was to pass a propertyMap that would map out how each JSON property matched to a Realm property. So it would look something like this inside the propertyMap array.

`"name" : { property, object in object.setValue(property.1.string!, forKey: "name")}`

Comment: So doesn't it sound like the problem is with the closure? Maybe include the code for that. Maybe also print/debug to ensure that `for object in json` only executes once. If you break at `realm.add`, hover over `withObject` and click on the (i), what do you see?

Comment: Ah, withObject is being set to the data on the first object in my JSON. Then it never changes. I was hoping that after each pass it would be the next iteration's data. I'm assuming that when I'm calling my closure, it's just passing a copy of withObject?

Comment: No, passing objects in Swift is by reference. I will add an answer to show you what I'm thinking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what your after - you want to call parseJSON, and have it create multiple `Object` instances, and use a closure that will set the properties for each instance. In that case, you should use generics to pass in the `Object` subclass type, and create a new instance each iteration. Along the lines of:

```
class func parseJSON<T: Object>(json: JSON, withType: T.Type, propertyMap: [String: (property: (String, JSON), object: Object) -> ()]) {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write({
        for object in json {
            let newObject = T()
            for property in object.1 {
                if let propertyMap = propertyMap[property.0] {
                    propertyMap(property: property, object: withObject)
                }
            }
            realm.add(newObject)
        }
    })
}
```

And then you call it like:

```
ViewController.parseJSON(JSON, withType: MyClass, propertyMap: myPropertyMap)
```

Comment: That's exactly it. Since Realm is a little odd, the only thing I had to change was withType: Module().dynamicType. Thanks so much for your help Michael!